# Django Templates and MongoDB _id

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-templates

```
Variables and attributes may not begin with underscores: 'value._id'
```

How does one reference the `_id` of an item gotten from MongoDB in Django Templates?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) would help:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='private')
def private(obj, attribute):
    return getattr(obj, attribute)
```

You can use it this way:

```
{{ value|private:'_id' }}
```

Comment: How much slower is a filter than a direct reference? Should I benchmark this first or use `$project` in MongoDB when obtaining the set instead to coarse it into 'id'? (lists may be a few hundred items)

Comment: @user3467349 if performance really matters here, I'd use `$project` to have a "non-private" attribute name since while using the template filter it would be an extra function call for every object. But, don't optimize prematurely, measure. Thanks.

Comment: If passing dictionaries to templates instead of objects, use the following filter: `def private(dic, key): return dic[key]`