# Django and Pymongo - Take multiple inputs and update a single field in all the objects

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms, pymongo

### Update multiple documents in django-mongodb with user inputs

I have a form which is meant to update all the price attribute of the objects in the product_details collection of my mongoDB.It is like Bulk price updating feature.I have tried few but finding it difficult.
Please suggest the method to do so in django.
***How can I update the price of multiple products using the same form and view?***

[image]

**price.html**

```
 <form class="col s12" action="{% url "bulk" %}" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Update<i class="material-icons right">cloud</i>
  </button>
    {% for r in result %} 



               <div class="col s6 m7">
                  <div class="card horizontal">
                    <div class="card-image"  >
                      <img class ="materialboxed" width="650" src="{{r.ppro}}" style="width:100px;
                 height:150px;
                 max-width:100%;
              max-height:100%;" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-stacked">
                      <div class="card-content">
                        <p style="font-size:15px;">{{r.ptitle}}<br>{{r.price}}</p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="card-action">

                        <div class="input-field col s4">
                          <input id="input_text" type="text" name=price  value="{{r.price}}"  data-length="10">
                          <label for="input_text">Price</label>
                        </div>



                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>


{% endfor %}


</form>

  </div>
```

---

**views.py**

```
def bulk_price(request):


    product_list= user_db.product_details.find({"shop_id":request.session["_id"]})
    user_data = user_db.store_details.find_one({"_id":request.session["_id"]})

    if product_list is not None:
            return render(request,'price.html',{'result':product_list,'status':user_data['status']})
    return render(request,'price.html')
```

**mongoDB structure of product_details object**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your input field name should be unique, you can use product id as name -

```
<input id="input_text" type="text" name="{{r.object_id}}"  value="{{r.price}}"  data-length="10">
```

Now, in the Django view, you can iterate through all the post data received from the form and update the database. Here is the code that should work -

```
def bulk_price(request):
    #If request method is POST, update the database 
    if request.method == "POST":
        for key in request.POST: #Iterate through POST variables
            value = request.POST[key]
            try:
                objectId = ObjectId(key)
            except Exeption as e:
                #The key is not a valid object id, it might be csrfmiddlewaretoken or some other post data
                continue
            user_db.product_details.update_one(
                    {'_id': objectId},
                    {'$set': {'price': value}}, 
                    upsert=False
                )

    #Render the update price page         
    product_list= user_db.product_details.find({"shop_id":request.session["_id"]})
    user_data = user_db.store_details.find_one({"_id":request.session["_id"]})
    if product_list is not None:
            return render(request,'price.html',{'result':product_list,'status':user_data['status']})
    return render(request,'price.html')
```

Don't forget to import ObjectId():

```
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
```

**Note:** To use MongoDB ObjectID in Django template, you will need a custom template filter. Refer to this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/24936772/8039601

Comment: Thanx dude.... It worked wonderfully... Stackoverflow please give him 100 reputations for this.