# Variables and attributes may not begin with underscores in django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-template-filters

Creating a private filter works fine for this case:

```
   {{ value|private:'_id' }}
```

but for this case it doesn't work:

```
   {% url 'value.show' value|private='_id' %}
```

Is there any way around this problem?

Filter example:
[Django Templates and MongoDB _id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24936601/django-templates-and-mongodb-id)

I am using couchdb with mongo query.

```
TemplateSyntaxError 
Variables and attributes may not begin with underscores: 'value._id'
Request Method: GET
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
Variables and attributes may not begin with underscores: 'value._id'
Python Version: 3.6.4
```

Comment: ... don't use an underscore?

Comment: Can you post the full error you are getting? where do you retrieve `_id` and can you set it to a new var like `id_to_display` in a way that the template wont fight?

Comment: Thanks, but not an options in this case cause I'm using couchdb

Comment: did you tried: `{% private='_id' as myNewID %}` then `{% url 'value.show' myNewID %}` ?

Comment: @ChihebNexus you mean  {% private='_id' as myNewID %}  .. this way i will end up in the same problem

Comment: @abedmaatalla, yes it was a typo error ... So then, can you add the error log to your question ?

Comment: @register.simple_tag
    def underscoreTag(obj, attribute):
        obj = dict(obj)
        return obj.get(attribute)

Thank " Chiheb Nexus ", I used your proposition also.

    {% underscoreTag value "_id" as id %}

Comment: I have the same error, Hove you solve it please let me know

Comment: @DeependraSingh i solved this by saving data in variable then called for url {% functionName value "_id" as id %} then {{ url "value.show" id}}

Answer (score 1):

Just to make the answer of @abed maatalla a bit more clearer.
I had the same problem, which was an API I was querying and converting to json.

The solution is to create a template tag that transforms that `_id` which cannot be read in the django template inside of the template tag (python file) and then output a result without an underscore which is usable in the django template.

This is a template tag file called `tagger.py`

```py
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def underscoreTag(obj, attribute):
    obj = dict(obj)
    return obj.get(attribute)
```

Then in your django html template

```
{% load tagger %}
<td> {% underscoreTag order "_id" as id %} {{ id }} </td>
```

Note that `order` is an json object payload i am receiving from the API that has the `_id` key in it.